# Swift: UITextField IBAction - EditingChanged - Button stays enabled, even though textfield values are changed?

Tags: ios, if-statement, swift, uibutton, edit

I have two IBActions for when two different text field's EditingChanged. Inside of these methods, I have an if statement that enables a button if two UITextFields both contain integers. The problem is, when the button becomes enabled, is stays enabled, even though if I edit the text field and change them so they have characters besides integers. How can I fix it? Please be thorough and clear when you provide the code because I am new to programming. Here's the code I have so far if you were wondering:

```
@IBAction func calorieNumberEditingChanged(sender: AnyObject) {
    // If both variables are true and the text fields contain integers, enable button
    if self.yourWeightFilled && self.calorieNumberFilled {
        self.calculateButton.enabled = true
    }
}
@IBAction func yourWeightEditingChanged(sender: AnyObject) {
    // If both variables are true and the text fields contain integers, enable button
    if self.yourWeightFilled && self.calorieNumberFilled {
        self.calculateButton.enabled = true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is similar to Evan's answer, but we can simplify the code.

```
func validateCalculateButton() {
    self.calculateButton.enabled = 
        (self.yourWeightFilled && self.calorieNumberFilled)
}

@IBAction func calorieNumberEditingChanged(sender: AnyObject) {
    self.validateCalculateButton()
}

@IBAction func yourWeightEditingChanged(sender: AnyObject) {
    self.validateCalculateButton()
}
```

And truly, there's no need to have two separate `@IBAction` methods here.  You could link both UI elements into the same method unless you need to do separate actions for each that you've not included in your code posted here.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding else statements and changing them back to not being enabled.

```
@IBAction func calorieNumberEditingChanged(sender: AnyObject) {
    // If both variables are true and the text fields contain integers, enable button
    if self.yourWeightFilled && self.calorieNumberFilled {
        self.calculateButton.enabled = true
    } else {
        self.calculateButton.enabled = false
    }
}
@IBAction func yourWeightEditingChanged(sender: AnyObject) {
    // If both variables are true and the text fields contain integers, enable button
    if self.yourWeightFilled && self.calorieNumberFilled {
         self.calculateButton.enabled = true
    } else {
        self.calculateButton.enabled = false
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This helped! An easy fix too (can't believe I didn't catch that)!